# Posting data without a form in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'd like to have a button do a simple POST in order to kick-off some work in the controller on the backend:

```
<button type="button" asp-action="DoIt">Do it<button>
```

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoIt()
{
}
```

Can I do this in ASP.NET Core without using a form?

I know I can do something like this:

```
<button onClick="$.post('/MyController/DoIt');" type="button">DoIt</button>
```

But it would be cool if something similar to following would be possible:

```
<button asp-controller="DoIt" asp-method="POST" type="button">DoIt</button>
```

Ideally, ValidateAntiForgeryToken would be supported too...

Comment: No,you can't. Post with a form is an HTTP standard, not asp.net core standard, so you can only use ajax or post with a form.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make an ajax call from javascript.

[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) example.

```
fetch("URL", {
    method: "POST",          // HTTP Method
    body: JSON.stringify({}) // Data to send
});
```

[JQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "",                 // URL to post to
    method: "POST",          // HTTP Method
    data: JSON.stringify({}) // Data to send
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I already mentioned I can do this simply with onClick and Ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
 HTML
------
    @Html.Hidden("cancelOrder", Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")) 


    AJAX Call
   ---------- 
    $.ajax({
            url: $("#cancelOrder").val(),
            type: "POST",
            data: { ID: Id},
            success: function (_result) {
                //Success
            }
        });



    Method
    ------
    public JsonResult MethodName()
            {
    bool _status = true;
                try
                {                
                    return Json(_status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks but I already mentioned I can do this simply with onClick and Ajax